# Criteria API Path Navigation With List

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

How we can compare list of fileds with Criteria API path navigation

```
criteriaBuilder.equal(propertyRoot.join("amenities")
        .join("interiors").<String>get("name"), "Gym");
```

I am getting error with the above code

Property Entity

```
class Property {
 ...
 @OneToOne(
        mappedBy = "property",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL
 )
 @JsonManagedReference
 private Amenities amenities;
}
```

Amenities Entity

```
class Amenities {
 ...
 @OneToMany(
        mappedBy = "amenities",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL
 )
 @JsonManagedReference
 private List<Interiors> interiors;
}
```

Interiors Entity

```
public class Interirios {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 private int id;
 private String name;
}
```

Comment: The criteria query you wrote has no meaning at all, you want to compare of a field with 'in' expression and join predicate ?

Comment: Yes, I want to fetch records with nested objets

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what do you want with provided select expression and criteria query, but i can imagine you want to make a join from some other associated entity and having `in` expression as [predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Predicate.html).

You asked

> How we can compare list of records with CriteriaBuilder and having join upon association.

You need to pass two predicates, one for `join` consideration an the other one for `in` expression. One practice to do so

```
Root<R> root = query.from(type);
Join<R, ?> join = root.join("association_field", JoinType.LEFT);
criteriaQuery.select(root.get("path+selection").get("some_atribute_in_current_path")).where(join.on(root.get("in_expersion_field").in(some_list)).getOn())
```

Just for clarifying again, the `"in_expersion_field"` is stands for the attribute that you would like to have `in` clause with some give list.